# Unable to remove symlinks after running npm link

Tags: node.js, npm

I created some executable in my project and defined the commands in the `bin` property in `package.json`

```
"bin": {
   "cmd1": "./scripts/cmd1.js",
   "cmd2": "./scripts/cmd2.js",
}
```

Then I ran `npm link`, symlinks were created in `.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin` (because I am using nvm).

The thing is, after I updated my scripts (cmd1.js / cmd2.js), it doesn't seem like the changes are reflected when I run `cmd1` or `cmd2`. It looks like I will have to remove the executables in `.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin`, and run `npm link` again. Seems like a hassle. And `npm unlink` doesn't work at all because it shows "Must provide a package name to remove" but I am not unlinking another package.

How to solve this situation?

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem, and then found this post: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1946

I was able to get rid of the link by running this:

```
$ npm unlink -g
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient solution for me was to type these commands in this order:

1. Observe the global node_modules directory location:

```
$ npm root -g
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/lib/node_modules
```

2. Navigate to that directory and observe the directories that are symlinks to remove:

```
$ cd /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/lib/node_modules

$ ls -al

total 0
drwxr-xr-x  10 username  staff  320 28 Mar 08:27 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 username  staff  128 20 Feb 20:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 username  staff   64 28 Mar 08:26 @yolo
drwxr-xr-x   8 username  staff  256 20 Feb 20:05 something
drwxr-xr-x  10 username  staff  320 27 Mar 11:24 eslint
lrwxr-xr-x   1 username  staff   53 27 Mar 12:58 forget-me-soon -> ../../../../../../dev/uniquename/some-test/botched-thing
lrwxr-xr-x   1 username  staff   45 27 Mar 12:30 some-bad-test -> ../../../../../../dev/uniquename/some-bad-test
drwxr-xr-x  12 username  staff  384 20 Feb 20:05 npm
lrwxr-xr-x   1 username  staff   44 15 Mar 11:24 botched-config -> ../../../../../../dev/uniquename/botched-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 username  staff   45 27 Mar 12:29 steven-segal -> ../../../../../../dev/uniquename/some-bad-test
```

3. Remove the symlinks

```
$ rm -rf forget-me-soon
$ rm -rf some-bad-test
$ rm -rf botched-config
$ rm -rf steven-segal

$ ls -al
# nothing bad left
```

4. Re-check npm's awareness of linked modules:

```
$ npm ls -g --depth=0 --link=true
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/lib
└── (empty)
```

Answer (score -1):

In windows, you can also delete the directory here:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```